# Convert numpy array from space separated to comma separated in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

This is data in .csv format file
generally we expect array/ list with [1,2,3,4] comma separated values
which it seems that nothing happened in this case

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
data_array = data.values

print(data_array)

print(type(data_array[0]))
```

and here is the output data

```
[16025788 179 '179batch1640694482' 18055630 8317948789 '2021-12-28'
 8315780000.0 '6214' 'CA' Nan Nan 'Wireless' '2021-12-28 12:32:46'
 '2021-12-28 12:32:46']

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So, i am looking for way to find array with comma separated values

Comment: can you paste (sample) output of `head file.csv` from your command line?

Comment: Have you already had a look in the [documentary](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) of `pd.read_csv`? If you want to read .csv files you can add parameters e.g.: `data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=' ', decimal='.')`. In case you want to open a csv file which you have saved before with python you can also add the parameter  `delimiter=','` to your _csv saving code line_

Comment: Otherwise if you have loaded your csv-file you can edit it afterwards by using `data_2 = data[data.columns[0]].str.split(' ', expand=True)` which transforms it into an array. Your output is kind of difficult to understand, it looks like a one-liner for me

Comment: You are confused about the display. Numpy arrays display with spaces, lists with commas.  But try `print(repr(data_array))`

Comment: @hpaulj actually it will convert data as string format

Comment: Arrays aren't separated by *anything*, they are *arrays*

Answer (score 0):

Okay so simply make the changes:

```
converted_str = numpy.array_str(data_array)
converted_str.replace(' ',',')
print(converted_str)
```

Now, if you want to get the output in <class 'numpy.ndarray'> simply convert it back to a numpy array. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Without the `csv` or dataframe (or at least a sample) there's some ambiguity as to what your `data` array is like.  But let me illustrate things with sample.

```
In [166]: df = pd.DataFrame([['one',2],['two',3]])
```

the dataframe display:

```
In [167]: df
Out[167]: 
     0  1
0  one  2
1  two  3
```

The array derived from the frame:

```
In [168]: data = df.values
In [169]: data
Out[169]: 
array([['one', 2],
       ['two', 3]], dtype=object)
```

In my Ipython session, the display is actually the `repr` representation of the array.  Note the commas, word 'array', and dtype.

```
In [170]: print(repr(data))
array([['one', 2],
       ['two', 3]], dtype=object)
```

A `print` of the array omits those words and commas.  That's the `str` format.  Omitting the commas is normal for `numpy` arrays, and helps distinguish them from lists.  But let me stress that this is just the display style.

```
In [171]: print(data)
[['one' 2]
 ['two' 3]]
In [172]: print(data[0])
['one' 2]
```

We can convert the array to a list:

```
In [173]: alist = data.tolist()
In [174]: alist
Out[174]: [['one', 2], ['two', 3]]
```

Commas are a standard part of list display.

But let me stress, commas or not, is part of the display. Don't confuse that with the underlying distinction between a `pandas` dataframe, a `numpy` array, and a Python list.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a normal python list first:

```py
print(list(data_array))
```